# Restrict customer email to current user when creating a coupon

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm creating a function to make a new coupon on every purchase in woocommerce. I'd like to restrict the customer email to the current user but haven't been able to successfully use dynamic values in the settings:

```
  $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
      if ( $order->user_id > 0 ) {

$coupon_code = 'UNIQUECODE'; // Code
$amount = '10'; // Amount
$discount_type = 'ign_store_credit';
$customer_email = ''; // How do I dynamically use the current user's email here?

$coupon = array(
    'post_title' => $coupon_code,
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => 1,
    'post_type'     => 'shop_coupon'
);

$new_coupon_id = wp_insert_post( $coupon );

// Add meta
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'discount_type', $discount_type );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'coupon_amount', $amount );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'individual_use', 'no' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'product_ids', '' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'exclude_product_ids', '' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'usage_limit', '' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'expiry_date', '' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'apply_before_tax', 'yes' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'free_shipping', 'no' );
update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'customer_email', $customer_email );
```

I've tried $user->user_email, $user_email

Comment: i've restored the question

Answer (score 0):

Using Woocommerce version 3+ [CRUD setters and getters methods](https://woocommerce.wordpress.com/2016/10/27/the-new-crud-classes-in-woocommerce-2-7/) to create a new coupon with email restriction from the order billing email:

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Order object
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

 // Only for registered customers
if ( $order->get_user_id() > 0 ){

    // Coupon settings
    $coupon_code    = 'UNIQUECODE';
    $discount_type  = 'ign_store_credit';
    $coupon_amount  = '10'; // Amount
    $customer_email = $order->get_billing_email();

    // Get a new instance of the WC_Coupon object
    $coupon = new WC_Coupon();

    // Set the necessary coupon data
    $coupon->set_code( $coupon_code );
    $coupon->set_discount_type( $discount_type );
    $coupon->set_amount( $coupon_amount );
    $coupon->set_email_restrictions( array( $customer_email ) );

    // Save the data
    $coupon->save();
}
```

This way the code is lighter, efficient and more compact.

Tested and works.